# Realm and parceler in Android Studio red error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, realm

[image]

[image]

This class in the build/intermediates/classes/debug/ target

If there is a way (such as a plug-in) to add classpath to build/intermediates/classes/debug/

Comment: Could you share your build details?  In particular, are you using the android-apt plugin?

Comment: Most likely you are missing the APT plugin as described here: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler#getting-parceler

Comment: o no,I didn't use the apt plugin.....try it

Comment: @henjue does it work now?

Comment: Try to remove line 7 and 14, build, and add the lines again.

Comment: I know the problem. Comment out the code                                                                   //    provided 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.1'